# Set size of video widget in Qt

Tags: qt, phonon

I am a novice Qt programmer who is trying to use the Qt phonon tool.

I have created this program with the help of an online tutorial. I was able to load a video.avi file in my program but the size of video in frame is very small. I've tried to increase the size of the video with my very poor Qt knowledge. Here is my code:

```
simpleplayer::simpleplayer(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    Phonon::VideoPlayer *videoPlayer = new Phonon::VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory, this);
    videoPlayer->play(Phonon::MediaSource("/home/sabbir/Downloads/heli2.avi"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Phonon::VideoPlayer` inherits [QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-videoplayer.html), so you should be able to set the size using the [size property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop)

I haven't used Phonon myself, so I'm not sure if your video will scale with the `Phonon::VideoPlayer`?

Comment: thanks a ton for your feedback. Actually I wanted to develop a video player using qt framework and the aim was to detect object and number of object that has been detected using opencv from some video file to my application..do you think using phonon will be right choice or gstreamer has been better proven functionality for my purpose ??

Comment: @muktoshuvro np, please upvote if you find it useful. As for using Phonon vs GStreamer, I don't know? Maybe as that in a new question.